# Case Sensitive COUNTIF

Tags: vba, case-sensitive

I was trying to use `COUNTIF` to count "Pass" in a specific column. But it counts  both "Pass" and "PASS". How do I make it case sensitive?

```
Cells(iRow, iCol).Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & name & "!H6:H500,""Pass"")"
```

Comment: Excel, and Excel formulas, are not case-sensitive by default (and design). It is possible to write a *complicated* formula that would distinguish case, but I would first question why you need to distinguish between Pass and PASS?

Comment: @AndyG Hey thanks for your response. I was trying to count the number of Pass(s) to make a table. The "PASS" is the status for the portion of the specific column. I am new to VBA. So I don't know what keywords to search in Google to find the directions.

Comment: This has little to do with VBA, you are inserting a formula and Excel itself isn't case sensitive.

Comment: @AndyG Thanks, I just fixed. I used SUMPRODUCT function instead of COUNTIF.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, Excel isn't case sensitive. I recommend that you use Replace (which has a 'Match case' option) to replace all occurrences of 'PASS' with some other word. You can do this in code if necessary - record a macro.

Alternatively, insert an additional column using a formula like this:

```
=AND(A1="Pass",CODE(MID(A1,2,1)=97))
```

This will create a column with TRUE if the word is 'Pass' and the second letter is a lower-case 'a'. You can extend this formula if you want to check more than one character.

Then your COUNTIF function can refer to this column rather than the original. (You can hide the column.)

Attempting to do this in a single formula requires an (in my opinion) unnecessarily complicated array formula. **Edited**: the formula isn't that complicated though, see @Cor_Blimey 's comment.

---

Excel is not case-sensitive so users using the same word 'pass' to have two distinct meanings is not helpful - and error prone.

Comment: EXACT(stringA,stringB) will perform a case-sensitive comparison, but yes - this can't be done within the Countifs so therefore either an array formula or a working column

Comment: also, the array formula would be trivial so I would argue a working column is more complicated - `=SUM(IF(EXACT(A1:A10,"PASS"),1,0))`

Comment: @Cor_Blimey I had forgotten about EXACT, thanks. Personally, I prefer the Replace option, and user education.